# Compute a function in a point using cubic spline

Tags: c++, cubic-spline

I am trying to compute a function in a point using cubic spline.

Here is my code:

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

class cubic_spline
{
private:
    // Структура, описывающая сплайн на каждом сегменте сетки
    struct spline_tuple
    {
        double a, b, c, d, x;
    };

    spline_tuple *splines; // Сплайн
    std::size_t n; // Количество узлов сетки

    void free_mem(); // Освобождение памяти

public:
    cubic_spline(); //конструктор
    ~cubic_spline(); //деструктор

    // Построение сплайна
    // x - узлы сетки, должны быть упорядочены по возрастанию, кратные узлы запрещены
    // y - значения функции в узлах сетки
    // n - количество узлов сетки
    void build_spline(const double *x, const double *y, std::size_t n);

    // Вычисление значения интерполированной функции в произвольной точке
    double f(double x) const;
};

cubic_spline::cubic_spline() : splines(NULL)
{

}

cubic_spline::~cubic_spline()
{
    free_mem();
}

void cubic_spline::build_spline(const double *x, const double *y, std::size_t n)
{
    free_mem();

    this->n = n;

    // Инициализация массива сплайнов
    splines = new spline_tuple[n];
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        splines[i].x = x[i];
        splines[i].a = y[i];
    }
    splines[0].c = 0.;

    // Решение СЛАУ относительно коэффициентов сплайнов c[i] методом прогонки для трехдиагональных матриц
    // Вычисление прогоночных коэффициентов - прямой ход метода прогонки
    double *alpha = new double[n - 1];
    double *beta = new double[n - 1];
    double A, B, C, F, h_i, h_i1, z;
    alpha[0] = beta[0] = 0.;
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        h_i = x[i] - x[i - 1], h_i1 = x[i + 1] - x[i];
        A = h_i;
        C = 2. * (h_i + h_i1);
        B = h_i1;
        F = 6. * ((y[i + 1] - y[i]) / h_i1 - (y[i] - y[i - 1]) / h_i);
        z = (A * alpha[i - 1] + C);
        alpha[i] = -B / z;
        beta[i] = (F - A * beta[i - 1]) / z;
    }

    splines[n - 1].c = (F - A * beta[n - 2]) / (C + A * alpha[n - 2]);

    // Нахождение решения - обратный ход метода прогонки
    for (int i = n - 2; i > 0; --i)
        splines[i].c = alpha[i] * splines[i + 1].c + beta[i];

    // Освобождение памяти, занимаемой прогоночными коэффициентами
    delete[] beta;
    delete[] alpha;

    // По известным коэффициентам c[i] находим значения b[i] и d[i]
    for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        double h_i = x[i] - x[i - 1];
        splines[i].d = (splines[i].c - splines[i - 1].c) / h_i;
        splines[i].b = h_i * (2. * splines[i].c + splines[i - 1].c) / 6. + (y[i] - y[i - 1]) / h_i;
    }
}

double cubic_spline::f(double x) const
{
    if (!splines)
        return std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN(); // Если сплайны ещё не построены - возвращаем NaN

    spline_tuple *s;
    if (x <= splines[0].x) // Если x меньше точки сетки x[0] - пользуемся первым эл-том массива
        s = splines + 1;
    else if (x >= splines[n - 1].x) // Если x больше точки сетки x[n - 1] - пользуемся последним эл-том массива
        s = splines + n - 1;
    else // Иначе x лежит между граничными точками сетки - производим бинарный поиск нужного эл-та массива
    {
        std::size_t i = 0, j = n - 1;
        while (i + 1 < j)
        {
            std::size_t k = i + (j - i) / 2;
            if (x <= splines[k].x)
                j = k;
            else
                i = k;
        }
        s = splines + j;
    }

    double dx = (x - s->x);
    return s->a + (s->b + (s->c / 2. + s->d * dx / 6.) * dx) * dx; // Вычисляем значение сплайна в заданной точке.
}

void cubic_spline::free_mem()
{
    delete[] splines;
    splines = NULL;
}

int main(void) {

    const size_t n(70000);
    double* x = new double[n];
    double* y = new double[n];

    for(size_t i(0); i < n; ++i) {
        x[i] = (1e-100)*i;
        y[i] = (x[i]-2)*8;
    }

    cubic_spline cs;
    cs.build_spline(x, y, n);
    std::cout << cs.f(2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the result for `(x-2)*8` function in 2 point to be `0`, but what I am getting is `-16`.

If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.If anyone knows, please, tell me what is wrong here.

Actually I took the code from [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD). It is solely for learning purposes.

Comment: Why did you expect it to be 0.479425?

Comment: @wally, I computed it using the calculator.

Comment: `5.88902e+0.69` isn't a valid number. Could you edit the question and give the actual number?

Comment: You may just be running into the difference between degrees and radians. Computers always use radians, but sometimes calculators use degrees.

Comment: You may want to start your first `for` loop at ` and assign to `alpha[i+1]`.  This would eliminate the need to calucluate `i-1` four times.  Likewise for the other loop.

Comment: Your arrays have n elements, but you only use n-1.  Is that what you expect?

Comment: @stark, I updated the question. Thank you.